# Task bar button to print screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, desktop-computer

before my Pc was upgraded from XP to Win 7 I had a button on my Task bar that allowed me to print the screen by just clicking on it and now I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Snipping Tool app mentioned earlier or just PrtSc (or Print Screen) key on your keyboard. Alternatively you can use Alt with this key to capture just active window.

There is a nice wikihow page about that one: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-%22Print-Screen%22-Function-on-a-Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snipping tool, it's a bit handier than normal screenshots because you can select an area. It'll be 2 clicks instead of 1